# Voltage spike when switching on 12V circuit

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, voltage-measurement

I connected a [dfrobot DC-DC Buck Converter 7-24V to 5V 4A](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/SKU_DFR0831_DC_DC_Buck_Converter_7_24V_to_5V_4A) to a 12 VDC battery via a switch, as per the supplier's diagram. When I turned the switch on the input of the converter fried.

It's the second one that's fried but the first one worked fine for a few uses. Eventually it fried when the switch was closed. The product is rated up to 24 V but on the back it says 30 V.

Removing the converter and using a multimeter connected to the supply, there are OL (overload) and 35 V readings before it settles to 12.96 V in about 1 sec.

Is this normal for a 12 VDC system or is it an artefact of the multimeter measurement? A 35 V spike would obviously fry the converter but why would a 12 V battery output almost three times its rating?

The wires are 11 A rated and there is about 1 metre between battery and converter via battery protect, fuse box and switch.

Everything else connected to the 12 V system is fine, including a buck/boost converter that drives a 10 W LED, another circuit that powers a USB socket and another one that powers a small 12 V LED.

Should I be using a Zener diode and resistor on the positive input?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

There isn't a schematic available for the product. All it says is:

> The module integrates durable ceramic chip capacitors of large
> capacity on the ports and large inductor that can reduce heat
> generation

Wiring diagram:

[image]

I replaced the fried converter with an LM2596S variable DC-DC converter set to 5 V output and it works perfectly in the above circuit.

The fried input on the converter:
[image]

Comment: Schematic of the buck converter please (questions on commercial products that don't have a schematic are likely to be closed). Also, a picture of your input wiring from battery to converter.

Comment: You can't diagnose spikes with a multimeter ... especially if it's an autoranging one.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. I've added wiring diagram and the blurb from the product page. Unfortunately there isn't a schematic available.

Comment: In engineering and in general, please remember to put a space between a quantity and its unit. So it's "5 V" rather than "5V".

Comment: thanks for that, will do

Comment: I think that space is not mandatory and situation dependent. Some people agree that for example with a capacitor, it's more clear to type 4u7 then 4.7 uF. (Like on a schematic).

Comment: Is it possible to make a picture of the fried convertor, both sides?

Comment: @RemyHx, you've got to remember this is for *a quantity and its unit*. On a schematic, referring to a part as "the 4u7" is a particular component with the value 4.7 uF, same as "10K" refers to a manufactured component with the value 10 kohms. On schematics, spaces in value names act as a separator so that can't be done. But in documentation, specs, file comments, Q&A site questions, letters, emails, etc. then a space is best practice. It can't be mandatory because there isn't an authoritative body to mandate it. But it's best practice. In MS Word, use a non-breaking space (CTRL-SHIFT-space).

Comment: I've added a picture of the fried input side. Looks like an ic.

Comment: “ Removing the converter and using a multimeter connected to the supply, there are OL (overload) and 35 V readings before it settles to 12.96 V in about 1 sec.” – I’m a little confused by this. Are you saying that you disconnected the DC–DC converter from the busbars, and then you connected a multimeter to the busbars, and the first reading you saw on the multimeter was 35 V? It would be incredibly weird to see 35 V across a 12 V battery. Is it possible that the BP65 was producing the 35 V?

Comment: I disconnected the load from the DC-DC converter and put a multimeter across the output +/- of the DC-DC converter and turned it on.

Comment: I get the impression these are designed for PCB use rather than on-site installations with long wire lengths of a metre and more. The other DC-DC converters I have are adjustable output and work fine even with 3 metre lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an electrolytic capacitor, or TVS diode, across the input.

The inrush overcharges the ceramic capacitors (which quickly lose capacitance as voltage rises, accelerating the overcharge*), until the regulator pops.  This is driven by excess supply inductance, which for these components can be merely on the order of 10 cm of wiring length.

*This is a unique property of type 2 ceramic capacitors; if this phenomenon didn't occur, the overvoltage would be limited to a bit less than double the input voltage, which would still be safe in this case.  Though a solution may still be desired in others.

The electrolytic dampens the resonance, drawing much more inrush current as a result (this will wear your switch), but keeping the voltage stable.  Or the TVS clamps the excess, so should be chosen for 12 V nominal and clamping somewhat less than the 24 V maximum; a P6KE15A might do.

Comment: thanks for that. The first time I tested one of these converters was with a smaller 12 V battery and about 10cm wires. The first one fried instantly. The second was fine for a few starts then it fried also, with the same wires.

Comment: I read up on TVS selection and thanks very much for pointing me in that direction. Now I understand what it's all about.

Comment: @codebrane You're welcome!